# Emulator hangs when running unit test cases

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-emulator

I am trying to run robotium test cases on emulator, I have more than 100 test cases to be executed. Problem: The emulator hangs in between of the execution of test cases. I need to proactively re-start the emulator and start the execution of test cases, I tried manually restarting the emulator but the test fails and the execution stops. What is the best practice or solution that I can take?

Answer (score 0):

Just use GenyMotion software instead of Emulator. Its better than emulator and also fast